# Understanding MTB Pedals

Tags: pedals, parts

This question is bugging me for a very long time. Look at the picture below.
[image: MTB Pedals]

Notice the area I have denoted with red circles. What is that? Does it represent something? Maybe something like position! If it represents position, which one is the right one? Should I pedal with that part in front or back? Why is that part on only side and not the other?

Comment: Definitely for "rat trap" pedal straps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's for mounting straps on the pedal. Here's a picture of a pedal with the straps on it:

[image]

Which side of the pedal should you use? On some pedals, one side has an axis that protrudes a bit, and the other side is flat; the latter is the one you should use. However, if both sides of the pedal are flat, feel free to use either side of the pedal.

Comment: Oh..... Now I get it....

Comment: Those things would be death on a proper MTB trail.

Comment: You know, people keep saying these things are dangerous, but I've not had a fall once. Of course, I don't tighten them all the way! (Clipless pedals seem insanely dangerous to me, IMO, but to each their own!)